# Dygraphs vertical zoom fails

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Found a set of parameters that seems to break vertical zooming (dragging up and down to zoom).  If you set up an inverted y-axis

```
valueRange: [14, 0]
```

and then call setAnnotations from within a zoomCallback

```
zoomCallback: function(minX, maxX, yRanges) {                         
                     this.setAnnotations([]);                        
                 }
```

Then the vertical zoom gets snapped back to the default. Horizontal zooming still works as expected. Does anyone know of a work-around? This may seem like an odd thing to do, but I only want to display annotations under certain zoom conditions. My code is not as simple as the example, of course, but I just boiled it down to the fewest conditions that I could in order to demonstrate the issue.  Here is a jsfiddle with the problem demonstrated.

http://jsfiddle.net/bvnLfhrm/27/

Comment: This seems more appropriate for the dygraphs [issue tracker](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: See https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/598